# in R, how can I calculate y/y and w/w in a data frame, based on different columns criteria?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I have quite a number of data frames with multiple columns with dates, regions, products, and sales numbers, covering different industries. here is a simplified example of what I'm talking about

```
Year = c((rep(c(2015),5)),(rep(c(2015)+1,5)),(rep(c(2015)+2,5)))
Month = as.factor(c("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY"))
Week = as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,5))
product_type = as.factor(c("Yellow", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Black"))
region = as.factor(c("North","North","North","South","South"))
Sales = c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,1500,2200,2800,4500,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,5200)
df = data.frame(date,product_type,region,Sales)
df

   Year Month Week product_type region Sales
1  2015   JAN    1       Yellow  North  1000
2  2015   FEB    2        Green  North  2000
3  2015   MAR    3          Red  North  3000
4  2015   APR    4         Blue  South  4000
5  2015   MAY    5        Black  South  5000
6  2016   JAN    1       Yellow  North  1500
7  2016   FEB    2        Green  North  2200
8  2016   MAR    3          Red  North  2800
9  2016   APR    4         Blue  South  4500
10 2016   MAY    5        Black  South  2000
11 2017   JAN    1       Yellow  North  3000
12 2017   FEB    2        Green  North  4000
13 2017   MAR    3          Red  North  5000
14 2017   APR    4         Blue  South  6000
15 2017   MAY    5        Black  South  5200
```

I'm trying to calculate y/y change for this data, filtered by both product_type and region. Again this is much more simplistic version, I have 52 weeks of data for each product and region over numerous years. The result should look like this.

```
Year Month Week product_type region Sales y/y
2016   JAN    1       Yellow  North  1500 50.0%
2016   FEB    2        Green  North  2200 10.0%
2016   MAR    3          Red  North  2800 ---
2016   APR    4         Blue  South  4500 ---
2016   MAY    5        Black  South  2000
2017   JAN    1       Yellow  North  3000
2017   FEB    2        Green  North  4000
2017   MAR    3          Red  North  5000
2017   APR    4         Blue  South  6000
2017   MAY    5        Black  South  5200
```

My problem is, the different data sets are of different lengths, may have some missing data for a year, or have completely different names.

My solution so far is to filter out one "product_type" and one "region" using data.table and tidyverse libraries to filter, and then use shift() to calculate the difference from one date from another. This requires me to create new data frames, hard code what I need to filter, which makes my code much too long for anyone else to understand or check. This solution also would take me quite some time to code and run in markdown, as my actual data sets have millions of rows of data.

Here is an example of the columns I'm dealing with

```
 "Company","Date","Year","Month","Week","Region","Product Type","Company Sales Units",
 "Company Value USD","Company ASP","Total Sales Units","Total Value USD","Total ASP",
 "% Share Units","% Share USD","ASP difference"
```

I am wondering if there is a way I can perform a calculation, but require that both the "product_type" and "region" value are the same, but that the date is different. Can this be done? If not, can this be done using SQL or python? I have some experience in both, but very rusty.

Any suggestions would be helpful too, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(product_type, region) %>%
  mutate("y/y" = if_else(Year == (lag(Year) + 1), (Sales/lag(Sales)) - 1, NA_real_))%>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(month_num = match(Month, toupper(month.abb))) %>%
  mutate("m/m" = if_else(month_num == lag(month_num) + 1, (Sales/lag(Sales)) - 1, NA_real_)) %>%
  mutate("w/w" = if_else(Week == (lag(Week) + 1), (Sales/lag(Sales)) - 1, NA_real_))

df
```

Lag looks at the prior row and if you group_by the product type and region, it will look at the prior row for each group.

For example, if the product_type and region was Yellow and North, it would take the 2016 sales number then divide by the 2015 sales number (and subtract 1 so it's .5 not 1.5).

The if_else will catch if it skips a year and only calculate the y/y% if the years are consecutive. Using if_else (as opposed to the base ifelse) requires the the true and false values be of the same type, hence the `NA_real_`.

The logic can be read as: if the current group row date is equal to the prior row's date + 1 (2016 == 2015 + 1), then calculate the y/y%, else NA.

Comment: Looking at your question more, this might run into the same issues you've mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I apply it to my data set, y/y is all NA. Looking into it now, but I changed df$Year to as.numeric(as.character()) to fix error caused by as.factor. my original data also includes Week and Month column so that may be why it's not working. I'm assuming this code would work if the only data included was only Year.

Comment: Maybe I can do something with ifelse where month and week must be the same, but year should be different.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the NA's. I can't seem to reproduce that on my side using the data you provided. Is the date column a double or POSIXct? Also I've added weeks and another line to calculate w/w%

Comment: This now works for me given the data you've supplied. Note I suggested an edit to your code.

Comment: Yes! okay so I hadn't realized that the data I had to group by both the month and week columns as there are slight changes to the Day that the data is recorded. Works wonders thank you

Answer (score 0):

This uses data.table, but you could do it with dplyr if you prefer

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[order(date),.(
  date = tail(date,-1), 
  `y/y` = 100*(exp(diff(log(Sales))/diff(date))-1)
  ),.(product_type,region)]
```

The formula is accounting for missing years by assuming a constant `y/y` return for the whole period from one data point to the next.

---

With the updated dataset this is a slightly different problem - presumably the Sales are per week, so if you want year-on-year or month-on-month changes you are going to have to do some aggregation first.

For the week-on-week calculation, you just need to work out what to put in a sequential date column, perhaps `df[,date := (Year - 2015)*52 + Week]` and then the above code will work. Or maybe you could work out the actual first day of the week each row refers to and use that.

Comment: Unfortunately not what I am looking for as the result is only those 4 categories.                   
             Product Type    Region Year  y/y
   1: Hot Bever.maker W. Europe    8 -100
   2: Hot Bever.maker W. Europe    8 -100
   3: Hot Bever.maker W. Europe    8  Inf
   4: Hot Bever.maker W. Europe    8 -100
   5: Hot Bever.maker W. Europe    8 -100

Comment: Is there some feature of your new data that breaks it? Perhaps it has 0s or missing values or repeats? If you extend your original question with some more info on what's going wrong I'm confident I'll be able to help you make the above solution work.

Comment: Also the resulting y/y numbers are either -100, or Inf

Comment: let me try putting another sample

Comment: -100, and Inf could come from the Sales value constantly changing between 0 and any finite number. The fragment in your first comment here, though, looks like the rows are identical which can't be right.